# Modify hovertext in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, hover, ggplotly

I'm creating a choropleth using simple features and ggplot, turning it into plotly output using the `ggplotly` function, then trying to update the hovertext info as shown below. I have no problem doing this on scatter plots, but no matter what I change with the choropleth, I seem to get the default hovertext.

There is no error messages, and I also tried experimenting with hovertemplate and continued to get the same result.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(plotly)
library(scales)

df <- spData::us_states

g <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df, aes(fill = total_pop_15)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "Total Pop 15", labels = comma) 

fig <- ggplotly(g) %>%
  style(hovertext = paste("State:", df$NAME,
                          "<br>Pop:", df$total_pop_15),
        hoveron = "fills")
fig
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your hoverinfo/text within your geom. And also set the `tooltip` to `"text"` in `ggplotly`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(plotly)
library(scales)

df <- spData::us_states

g <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = df, aes(fill = total_pop_15,
                         text = sprintf("State: %s<br>Pop: %s", NAME, total_pop_15))) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "Total Pop 15", labels = comma) 

ggplotly(g, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works! But I did have to put this line `ggplotly(plt, tooltip = "text") %>% style(hoveron = "fills")` at the end to keep it on fill instead of border.